# How can I display the TimeSpec within a QDateTimeEdit object?

Tags: qt

I am working in QT Creator and would like to add text within the widget that displays the TimeSpec for this DateTime widget which is UTC. For example, I want it to show "1/1/00 5:00:00 AM (UTC)" as opposed to what it's showing right now. I went through the property list and didn't see anything that would allow me to make this change. Is it possible?

[image: The DateTime widget]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the displayFormat to `M/d/yy h:mm:ss AP (t)` and the timeSpec to `UTC`:

[image]

[image]